# $2 not working in Perl search and replace for not-so-special case

Tags: regex, perl, curl, replace, csv

I am trying to add entries to a tsv file using webpage-based curl lookups per the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

my $file = "TfbG_peaks2.tsv";
open(INFO, $file) or die("Could not open file.");
#my $VNG = "VNG1649G";
my $query = "(\<title\>)([A-Za-z0-9\- ]*)";
foreach $line (<INFO>) {
        $line =~ /(^VNG\w*)/;
        $VNG = $1;
        my $url = "http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/?term=$VNG";
        my $page = `curl $url`;
        if ($page =~ /(\<title\>)(VNG)/) {
                $name = "hypothetical protein";
                $abbrev = " ";
                $longname = $name;
        }
        elsif ($page =~ /$query/) {
                $name = $2;
                $name =~ /^(\w+)(\s+)(([A-Za-z0-9\-]+\s*)+)/;
                $abbrev = $1;
                $longname = $3;
        }
        my @values = split('\t', $line);
        splice @values, 1, 0, $abbrev;
        splice @values, 2, 0, $longname;
        print join "\t", @values;
        print "\n";
}
```

The input tsv data file has lines that look like

`VNG1374G        Chromosome      1022977 1023252 4.184852806     2.877295983     3.362660404     3.961922335     3.932399564`

The only line in the page source of the webpages I am looking up that contains the `<title>`  HTML tag is like

`<title>trn26  [Halobacterium sp. NRC-1] - Gene - NCBI</title>`

for entries with a trn name and like

`<title>gspE1 type II secretion system protein [Halobacterium sp. NRC-1] - Gene - NCBI</title>`

or like

`<title>VNG1872C hypothetical protein [Halobacterium sp. NRC-1] - Gene - NCBI</title>`

for entries with a non-trn name.

The code works for non-trn names, i.e. prints either something like

`VNG0218G        gspE1   type II secretion system protein        Chromosome      186556  186979  4.072750978     2.233376793     2.684902216     3.714576271     3.52083442`

or something like

`VNG2556H                hypothetical protein    Chromosome      1917796 1918082 3.778968581     2.582944032     2.981130347     3.940093432     4.286983604`

but for trn entries prints

`VNGt26  <title>         Chromosome      1153828 1154334 4.879550683     3.730707809     5.515198268     5.30410069      5.328461226`

instead of the expected

`VNGt26  trn26         Chromosome      1153828 1154334 4.879550683     3.730707809     5.515198268     5.30410069      5.328461226`

Why should the trn case be any different? The webpage source  lines seem formatted in the same manner for the trn and non-trn cases and I can't see why my regex would fail for this case.

Also, I'm new to Perl so any suggestions on organization or keeping code clean & concise are welcome.

Comment: This question can be asked in under 10 lines. Could you please remove what isn't pertinent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$name =~ /^(\w+)(\s+)(([A-Za-z0-9\-]+\s*)+)/;` doesn't match, and thus doesn't change `$1`, `$2`, etc.

Comment: Thank you. Replacing it with `$name =~ /^(\w+)(\s+)(([A-Za-z0-9\-]+\s*)*)/;` seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using regex to grab the title of the page, you might consider using something that can extract bits of HTML:

```
use Mojo::UserAgent;

my $title = Mojo::UserAgent->new
    ->get($url)
    ->result
    ->dom
    ->at('title')
    ->all_text;
```

You can still get the HTML from curl, then use [Mojo::DOM] to get what you need:

```
my $html = `curl ...`;
my $title = Mojo::DOM->new($html)->mom->at('title')->all_text;
```